# Birational properties of canonical bundle 

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

What properties of a canonical bundle are preserved under birational isomorphism between
smooth projective varieties. In particular, is triviality of the canonical bundle preserved?

Comment: Let $X$ be a $K3$ surface and $Y$ the blowup of $X$ at a point. The blowdown map $\pi : Y \to X$ is a birational isomorphism and $X$ has trivial canonical bundle, but $Y$ does not.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally speaking, to your specific question, the answer is no.

See for example Hartshorne, Chapter V, Section 3.  On the other hand, numerous other properties are preserved (some of these are also mentioned in Hartshorne, for example, the geometric genus).   There are more subtle things as well, see any book on the *minimal model program* for example.

With regards to your original question, you might want to try looking up *crepant resolutions*.

Comment: Of course, I forgot about blow-ups, which change the canonical bundle.
If however the birational map is an isomorphism outside of a set of codimension at least 2, then triviality of the canonical bundle will be preserved. 

I'd like to know when to expect and not expect such birational correspondences. 

Comment: Besides "crepant resolutions" then, "flips" and "flops" might be quite relevant (the last two will be commonly found in sources related to the minimal model program, see for example the book by Kollar and Mori). Those last two are examples of birational transformations between (well, sometimes non-smooth) varieties which are isomorphisms in codim 1.

Comment: Sorry. I'm very new to this business. Isomorphism in codim 1 means what?

Comment: It means there exists subsets of codimension at least 2 in the source and target on whose complements the map is an isomorphism.

Comment: For instance, the "classical flop" (or "Atiyah's flop") is a birational map between 3-folds which, when one removes a line from the source and the target, gives an isomorphism. A good place to read about these things is Miles Reid's paper "Twenty-five years of 3-folds --- an old person's view".